# Evento close on click do Boostrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, html

Usando datepicker do jQueryUI por padrão o evento de clicar na data e o datepicker fechar funciona.

Como eu posso fazer isso no [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ?

**JS:**

```
$('#data').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  language: 'pt-BR',
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="data" class="form-control text-center" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fechar o datepicker automaticamente ao selecionar a data você pode usar inicializar o plugin com a opção `autoclose`.

```
$('#data').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  language: 'pt-BR',
  autoclose: true
});
```

Comment: não funciona esta opção, procurei  no google e achei no stackoverflow USA uma resposta igual a esta. e  também na documentação do plugin https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/

Comment: Esta opção está disponível a partir da versão 1.3.1 que pode ser baixada no [repositório oficial](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/archive/1.3.1.zip). [Neste demo](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&autoclose=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) você pode ver esta opção funcionando.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/wa5kp0pw/ que estranho, fiz um teste no jsfiddle e esta rodando, agora no meu sistema nao esta, e eu confirmei varias vezes a ordem dos arquivos, 1 jquery,2 bootstrap, 3 datepicker,4 funcoes,js que chama a datepicker

Comment: Não sei se você já tentou ou se é este o problema, mas limpar o cache do navegador pode ajudar. Talvez ainda esteja carregando a versão antiga.

Comment: tentei limpar  o cache antes também, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Alguma coisa no console?

Comment: sem mensagem no console... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByiDi-nlXfgVNXVFUmZGeTZjQlE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Você não atualizou o js do datepicker. O que está no seu projeto é uma versão de 2012 (js/plugins/datepicker.js).

Comment: Era isso mesmo, eu sempre renomeio o nome do arquivo pra ficar mais simples e semantico e na hora de substituir acabou nao o fazendo